# Triggering custom action in a silence mode

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I'm working on a setup that validate many user inputs by a custom action. The event "DoAction" of publish control are doing very good job, but I figured out that no one custom validation are triggered if I execute the setup in silence mode.

I tried InstallExecuteSequence like the Yen Tran's blog (http://yentran.org/blog/2013/09/27/wix-executing-custom-action-before-starting-windows-service/) but still not working.

```
<Frament>
<Binary Id="CALibrary" SourceFile="$(var.Project.Installer.CustomAction.TargetDir)CustomAction.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id ="ProxyCheck" BinaryKey="CALibrary" DllEntry="Proxy" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
<CustomAction Id ="ActivationCheck" BinaryKey="CALibrary" DllEntry="Activation" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
</Frament>

...

<Fragment>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ActivationCheck" Before="InstallInitialize" Overridable="yes">PROXYSERVER</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking... and when you say "not working" nobody knows what actually is happening.

Comment: I would like to figure out why my "Custom Action" was not triggering  on silent mode. There is no problem with this action, but it's been ignored by the installer on silent mode.

Answer (score 0):

With Orca.exe I found that the action was not configured in InstallExecuteSequence no matter what I do. Reviewing all the files for the thousandth time, I found that I was putting the instruction of InstallExecuteSequence in a wrong place, moved into the <Product> </Product> and then everything works well.

Comment: Something has to reference a fragment for it get included into your build.